# I need to make one folder private

Tags: htaccess

I'd like to make one specific folder in WordPress private and give access permission only for the administrator role.

What I can do for now is to make the folder private by .htaccess and give access permission to a specific IP address using .htaccess.

Is there any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by “folder”. WordPress doesn’t really have folders. At least not in a context that makes sense with your question.

Comment: you like wp-content,  wp-admin like this folder private in roboto.txt file?